# Remove a child from parent and add it as Sibling to Parent

Tags: javascript

I have a Bullet Region like

- Hello
- How
- are
- you

No i am selecting

are

and changing to Number Bullet.
so my list should change like

- Hello
- How

1. are

- you

1. want to end the Disc bullet after second child.
2. want to add Third child as sibling to parent.
3. Want to again make Disc bullet to fourth child and add it as sibling to parent.

How can i do this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: [a basic tutorial like this](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllists01.htm) should be helpful

Comment: I am iterating through the nodes and changing the style.But my nodes are like children to the Current UL node. I want to end the Current UL node and the modified childs has to be removed and inserted as siblings to current UL node.

Comment: If you can show the before and after HTML, we can much more easily help you with the script to convert the former to the latter.

Comment: "<ul style="list-style-type:circle"><li>Hello</li><li>how</li><ol style="list-style-type:upper-alpha"><li>are</li></ol><li>you[tyi</li></ul>"   my final HTML is like this.. But i want the OL to be created outside, not as a child to "ul"

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a non-trivial and very interesting problem. However, you need to first know a couple of things:

1. The bullets on a list item are determined by its list; `ul` is for unordered lists (ie. disk bullets), and `ol` is for ordered lists (ie. numbered bullets).
2. You cannot have an `li` without its parent being either `ul` or `ol`.
3. You cannot have a `ul` be a direct child of a `ol` or vice versa (they can be children of an `li` though, but then they'll be sublists)

This means that every time you switch a list, you need to make sure that the item you're switching has a parent of the correct (and opposite) type, and the items before and after it are also in (separate) lists of the correct type. You will in many cases need to create those lists (or delete them, when they become empty).

Anyway, words are worthless, here's the code (I'm  using jQuery, but the idea should be the same regardless of what you use):

```
$('li').on('click', function () { 
    var $listItem = $(this);
    var $list     = $(this).parent();
    var $items    = $list.children();
    var itemIndex = $items.index($listItem);
    var numItems  = $items.length;

    var curType = $list.is('ul')   ? 'ul' : 'ol';
    var newType = curType === 'ul' ? 'ol' : 'ul';

    var $prev = $list.prev();
    var $next = $list.next();

    if (itemIndex === 0) {
        // The item we're switching is the first Item in the list
        if (!$prev.is(newType)) {
            $prev = $('<' + newType + '/>');
            $prev.insertBefore($list);
        }
        $prev.append($listItem);
    } else if (itemIndex === numItems - 1) {
        // The item we're switching is the last Item in the list
        if (!$next.is(newType)) {
            $next = $('<' + newType + '/>');
            $next.insertAfter($list);
        }
        $next.prepend($listItem);
    } else {
        // The item is in the middle, we need to split the current list into 3.
        $tailList = $('<' + curType + '/>');
        $tailList.append($listItem.nextAll());
        $tailList.insertAfter($list);

        $middleList = $('<' + newType + '/>');
        $middleList.append($listItem);
        $middleList.insertAfter($list);
    }

    if (numItems === 1) {
        // list used to have only one Item, so it's now empty, and should be removed.
        $list.remove();

        if ($prev.is(newType) && $next.is(newType)) {
            // The two surrounding lists are of the same type and should be merged.
            $prev.append($next.children());
            $next.remove();
        }
    }
});
```

I'm using the click event on a list item to switch a list item. Here's a jsFiddle link for you to play around with the implementation and validate that everything works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/8Z9rf/

The code can definitely be optimized for speed/performance, but I was aiming for simplicity and clarity, I hope I managed to accomplish this.